# Nodejs logging module - production env

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules, winston, bunyan

I am currently working on NodeJS application project.

This application basically performs:

1. Interaction with Database (1000 request/response processing per min)
2. Server side processing logic using information obtained from database
3. Client request handling  (100 request for every 5 mins)

For any project, logging information is key to identify any failures/processing state.

I tried [winston](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston) nodejs log framework, but it happened that it does not support the following information:

1. File Name
2. Function Name
3. Line No
4. Process ID
5. Host name etc

Hence I decided to go for [bunyan](https://github.com/trentm/node-bunyan) logging framework. I understand Bunyan framework supports these things.

Please share your thoughts whether this can be used for production code.

If not possible, I fear how other nodejs projects used in many web application gets these information.

I could not get any production ready log framework in nodejs which supports these functionalities. 
I googled for information and search results  leads to winston/bunyan.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that bunyan does not support file name, function name and line number.

Comment: It is supporting. I tested it. Please check this link.                          https://github.com/trentm/node-bunyan/blob/master/README.md.                           Refer parameter "src"

Comment: You answer your own question in that link.  You asked if it can be used in production code and in the link you provided it specifically says, "WARNING: Determining the call source info is slow. Never use this option in production."

Answer (score -1):

If your question still actual, you can try this one

[@grdon/logger](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@grdon/logger)

**Usage example**

```
const logger = require('@grdon/logger')({
 defaultLogDirectory : __dirname + "/logs",
})
// ...

logger([process.argv], 'logfile.txt')
```

**Result will be**

```
Start:Wed Sep 22 2021 13:52:22 GMT+0400 
 
[
  [
   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
   'D:\\todel3\\test.js',
   [length]: 2
  ],
 [length]: 1
]
Trace:Object- File D:\grdon-test\test.js:6
Finish
```

filename, line, function names supported, and many other options

Comment: this answer was flagged for low quality, please better the answer with more supporting info and an explanation

Comment: code example and result provided :)